# Разбиение String на составляющие

Tags: c++, c

У меня есть файл с входными данными, в нем 4 строки по 4 столбца. В столбце указывается Фамилия, вид спорта, разряд и название клуба (через пробел). Как разделить строку и записать составляющие в соответствующую переменную?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



struct Sport
{
    string Surname;
    string Type;
    int Category;
    string Name;
};


int main()
{
    Sport sport;
    vector<Sport> vec;
    
    
    ifstream input;
    input.open ("example.txt");
    
    
    string line;
    
    if (input.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(input, line))  
            {
                 //Надо line разбить на слова и запихнуть в вектор
                
                
                //Как это сделать?
                sport.Surname = ";
                sport.Type = ;
                sport.Category = ;
                sport.Name = ;
                vec.push_back(sport);
                
            }

    }
    
    
    

        

    
    vector<Sport>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    
    for(it; it!=vec.end(); it++)
    {
        cout<< it->Surname;
        cout<< it->Type;
        cout<< it->Category;
        cout<< it->Name;
        cout<<endl;

    }
    
    return 0;
    
    
}
```

Comment: ну так вместо чтения строки с последующей разбивкой, читайте 4 отдельных слова. Где то так  `while (input >> it->Surname >> it->Type >> it->Category >> it->Name) {}`

Comment: Строку разбить на лексемы можно с помощью `strtok()`. Достаточно удобно. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok

Comment: можно, но оно тут не нужно. strtok - очень специфичная функция, ею можно пораниться, с std::string плохо работает.